# Changing Color of Navigation Bar Independently

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

Before I begin, please know that I have read through a number of StackOverflow posts on the topic, yet I've been unable to figure out how to apply many answers to my specific scenario.

In my Storyboard, I have a Table View with an embedded navigation controller, and a segue to another Table View with an embedded navigation controller.  Based on the design of my app, I am seeking the navigation bar in the first table view to have a different background (tint) color than the navigation bar in my second table view.  Here's my layout;

[image: Multiple Navigation Controllers]

Per the above, I set the color of my first Navigation Controller bar to be green, and my second Navigation Controller to be blue.  However, when I build and run the app, the second Table View has a **green** navigation controller, whereas I've set it to blue in Interface Builder.

I've tried to use the following code in my SecondTableViewController.swift file;

`navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()`
`self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()`

Is this possible?  Or am I misunderstanding how the navigation controller works?

Comment: you also need to set the translucency... self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set all UINavigationBar instances at once to the same color do this:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

To set per instance (as you need), try this:

```
self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = false
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Woodstock.  I gave that code a try, but I'm getting the same symptoms.  If I put that code in my **FirstTableViewController.swift** file, it changes the bar to green for both my first and second table views.  If I put that code in my **SecondTableViewController.swift** file, I cannot independently set the bar color for just my second table view.

Comment: Thanks @Woodstock.  I think I have a conceptual problem here.  I'm pretty sure your code is correct, but whatever I do to the navigation bar on the first Navigation Controller is all that will affect the second.  If I hide the Navigation Bar on the first Navigation Controller altogether, it hides it from the second.  If I try to hide the Navigation Bar on the second Navigation Controller but not the first, it's still visible.  It's like the second Navigation Controller will not listen to any coding, it only takes what it sees from the first.

Comment: Nevermind @Woodstock!  I got it.  I had made an error in how I was arranging the code which was resulting in the second Table View Controller not respecting my work.  Your code is correct.